# How to convert microsoft access time format with php

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

Can someone please help me with the following.

I am using php and sql to query a microsoft access database. I have a Date/Time field called "StartTime" that is set to "General date" format.

When inspecting the field from within the microft access GUI the date appears as "08:45:00".

My problem is when I retrieve this data with my php and sql and then display it in then write it to the browser it appears as follows "1899-12-30 09:00:00" **(let's call this 'long date format' for what i'm about to say**).

I have tried messing around with the php date function using the 'long date format' as the second argument but I can't seem to get it to display in the browser in the format "08:45:00".

Please can someone tell me what I need to do.

Thanks

Comment: That appears to just be storing a time, and ignoring the date portion. If you need to convert a date string to a timestamp in PHP you can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), but you may find that that particular date will give you problems on a 32-bit platform - it is outside the bounds of a 32-bit signed integer. On 64-bit platforms, `strtotime()` should do the job nicely and give you a value that you can pass to the second argument of `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that MS Access stores the date as a double with fractions. So you need to parse it accordingly.

The whole part of the number is the amount of days from Dec 30 1899. The fractional portion is the fraction of the day. So you need to multiply the fraction by 24 to get hours, multiply the resulting fraction by 60 to get minutes, and multiply the resulting fraction by 60 to get seconds.

Alternatively, you can multiply the fraction by 86400 (number of seconds in 24 hours), and then use a PHP function to convert the seconds into the time of day.

Check out this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210276

Answer (score 1):

You could ask Access' db engine to give you only the time portion of those Date/Time values as formatted strings:

```
SELECT Format(StartTime, "hh:nn:ss") AS time_only
FROM YourTable;
```

That way you wouldn't have to transform the values in PHP ... just use them.